# Breaking up a list into sublists with recursion

Tags: list, haskell, recursion, sublist

I'm trying to write a function with the type declaration `[(Int, Bool)] -> [[Int]]`. I want the function to only add `Int`s to the same nested sublist if the Boolean is `True`. However if the Boolean is `False`, I want the `Int` associated with the next `True` bool to be added to a *new* sublist. For example: An input of

```
[(1,True),(2,True),(3,False),(4,True),(5,False),(6,False),(7,True)]
```

should return

```
[[1,2],[4],[7]].
```

My code so far:

```
test:: [(Int, Bool)] -> [[Int]]
test xs = case xs of
    []->[]
    x:xs
        | snd x == True -> [(fst x)] : test xs
        | snd x == False -> test xs
```

I'm currently having issues on adding concurrent Ints to the same list if their bools are both `True`.

Comment: I edited my post to include my current code. I'm not sure how to add an int to an existing list within the list of lists.

Comment: [`span`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:span) might be useful here.

Comment: how would you use span to approach the problem?

Comment: @nickdoig like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58326464/849891). :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can break this problem into two sub-problems.

1. For any given list, take the head of this list and match it against the rest of list. There are two possibilities during this matching: i) You are successful i.e. you match, and if so, you collect the matched value and continue looking for more values, or ii) You fail, i.e. you don't match, and if so, you stop immediately and return the so far matched result with  rest of, not-inspected, list.

> ```
>    collectF :: (Eq a) => (a -> Bool) -> [a] -> ([a], [a])
>    collectF f [] = ([], [])
>    collectF f (x : xs) 
>     | f x = let (ys, zs) = collectF f xs in (x : ys, zs)
>     | otherwise = ([], x : xs)
> ```

2. Now that you have the collectF function, you can use it recursively on input list. In each call, you would get a successful list with rest of, not-inspected, list. Apply collectF again on rest of list until it is exhausted.

> ```
> groupBy :: (Eq a) => (a -> a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [[a]]
> groupBy _ [] = []
> groupBy f (x : xs) = 
>     let (ys, zs) = collectF (f x) xs in 
>     (x : ys) : groupBy f zs
>
> *Main> groupBy (\x y -> snd x == snd y) [(1,True),(2,True),(3,False),(4,True),(5,False),(6,False),(7,True)]
> [[(1,True),(2,True)],[(3,False)],[(4,True)],[(5,False),(6,False)],[(7,True)]]
> ```

I am leaving it to you to remove the True and False values from List. Also, have a look at List library of Haskell [1]. Hope, I am clear enough, but let me know if you have any other question.

[1] http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/src/Data.OldList.html#groupBy

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I'd write this:

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..), (<|))
import qualified Data.List.NonEmpty as NE

test :: [(Int, Bool)] -> [[Int]]
test = NE.filter (not . null) . foldr go ([]:|[])
  where
    go :: (Int, Bool) -> NonEmpty [Int] -> NonEmpty [Int]
    go (n, True) ~(h:|t) = (n:h):|t
    go (n, False) l = []<|l
```

Or with [Will Ness's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58021470/breaking-up-a-list-into-sublists-with-recursion/58314713#comment103030626_58314713):

```
import Data.List.NonEmpty (NonEmpty(..))

test :: [(Int, Bool)] -> [[Int]]
test = removeHeadIfEmpty . foldr prependOrStartNewList ([]:|[])
  where
    prependOrStartNewList :: (Int, Bool) -> NonEmpty [Int] -> NonEmpty [Int]
    prependOrStartNewList (n, True) ~(h:|t) = (n:h):|t
    prependOrStartNewList (n, False) l = []:|removeHeadIfEmpty l
    removeHeadIfEmpty :: NonEmpty [Int] -> [[Int]]
    removeHeadIfEmpty (h:|t) = if null h then t else h:t
```

Comment: we can produce not so many `[]`s in the first place. `go (n, False) l` can inspect the   `l` and if its first sublist is `[]`, just keep it as is. the laziness of not inspecting the `l` in that case is destroyed by the downstream `filter (not . null)` anyway. :) so there will in the end be only one extraneous `[]` at the head of produced list, at the most. (reason I know, this thing was already asked, and answered several years back... I remember there was an answer by Daniel Fischer, and possibly also by me).

Comment: @WillNess Good catch. I added a variant that takes advantage of that.

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly, drop the `False`s, grab the `True`s. With view patterns:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ViewPatterns #-}

test :: [(a, Bool)] -> [[a]]
test (span snd . dropWhile (not . snd) -> (a,b))
               | null a     =  [] 
               | otherwise  =  map fst a : test b
```

Works with infinite lists as well, inasmuch as possible.