# Capitalizing first letter of words while removing spaces (Haskell)

Tags: haskell

I'm just starting out in Haskell and this is like the third thing I'm writing, so, naturally, I'm finding myself a little stumped.

I'm trying to write a bit of code that will take a string, delete the spaces, and capitalize each letter of that string.

For example, if I input "this is a test", I would like to get back something like: "thisIsATest"

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps [] = []
toCaps xs = filter(/=' ') xs
toCaps (_:xs) =  map Char.toUpper xs
```

I think the method I'm using is wrong. With my code in this order, I am able to remove all the spaces using the `filter` function, but nothing becomes capitalize.

When I move the `filter` bit to the very end of the code, I am able to use the `map Char.toUpper` bit. When I map that function `Char.toUpper`, it just capitalizes everything "HISISATEST", for example. 
I was trying to make use of an if function to say something similar to

`if ' ' then map Char.toUpper xs else Char.toLower xs`, but that didn't work out for me. I haven't utilized `if` in Haskell yet, and I don't think I'm doing it correctly. I also know using "xs" is wrong, but I'm not sure how to fix it. 
Can anyone offer any pointers on this particular problem?

Comment: Well the last clause can never fire, since the second pattern `toCaps xs` will capture all possible input.

Comment: Turning warnings on using `-Wall` detects this error.

Comment: What should happen if there are leading spaces? Should `toCaps "   hey"` be `"hey"` (because `'h'` is the first non-space character) or `"Hey"` (because `'h'` is not the first character)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it might be better if you split the problem into smaller subproblems. First we can make a function that, for a given word will capitalize the first character. For *camel case*, we thus can implement this as:

```
import Data.Char(toUpper)

capWord :: String -> String
capWord "" = ""
capWord (c:cs) = toUpper c : cs
```

We can then use `words` to obtain the list of words:

```
toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps = go . words
    where go [] = ""
          go (w:ws) = concat (w : map capWord ws)
```

For example:

```
Prelude Data.Char> toCaps "this is a test"
"thisIsATest"
```

For *Pascal case*, we can make use of `concatMap` instead:

```
toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps = concatMap capWord . words
```

Comment: Isn't `go` just reimplementing `(>>=)`? `toCaps = (>>= capWord) . words`?

Comment: @amalloy: if I read the secs correctly the first character of the first word should not be capitalized (well that is suggested by the example). So I think it is basically constructing "camelCase" from a given string.

Comment: You could use `w++concatMap ...`.

Answer (score 3):

Inspired by [this answer from Will Ness](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57534683/7509065), here's a way to do it that avoids unnecessary Booleans and comparisons:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps = flip (foldr go (const [])) id
  where go ' ' acc _ =     acc Char.toUpper
        go x   acc f = f x:acc id
```

Or more understandably, but perhaps slightly less efficient:

```
import qualified Data.Char as Char

toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps = go id
  where go _ []       =     []
        go _ (' ':xs) =     go Char.toUpper xs
        go f (x  :xs) = f x:go id           xs
```

Comment: using functions instead of Booleans... I expect if we use Church encoded Booleans and simplify, this is the code we'd end up with! -- talking about efficiency, we can even make one more step and squash the reducer and the selector functions together, to get rid of those irritating `id`s, and end up with *two* reducer functions switching up between them. :) (only possible with [direct recursion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58048782/849891) of course; an *irregular* pattern like that wouldn't have its own name). I've posted it as an answer, below. (a very Prolog-ish like code, there). :)

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of ways of doing it, but if I were trying to keep it as close to how you've set up your example, I might do something like:

```hs
import Data.Char (toUpper)

toCaps :: String -> String
toCaps []         = []                    -- base case
toCaps (' ':c:cs) = toUpper c : toCaps cs -- throws out the space and capitalizes next letter
toCaps (c:cs)     = c : toCaps cs         -- anything else is left as is
```

This is just using basic recursion, dealing with a character (element of the list) at a time, but if you wanted to use higher-order functions such as `map` or `filter` that work on the entire list, then you would probably want to compose them (the way that Willem suggested is one way) and in that case you could probably do without using recursion at all.

It should be noted that this solution is brittle in the sense that it assumes the input string does not contain leading, trailing, or multiple consecutive spaces.

Comment: This doesn't work right if there's ever two spaces in a row.

Comment: It also doesn't work right if a space is the last character.

Comment: Thanks! Updated with a note about that.

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by [Joseph Sible](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7509065/joseph-sible) 's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58101548/849891), a *coroutines* solution:

```
import Data.Char

toCamelCase  :: String -> String
toCamelCase  []         =  []
toCamelCase  (' ': xs)  =  toPascalCase xs
toCamelCase  (x  : xs)  =          x : toCamelCase xs

toPascalCase :: String -> String
toPascalCase []         =  []
toPascalCase (' ': xs)  =  toPascalCase xs
toPascalCase (x  : xs)  =  toUpper x : toCamelCase xs
```

Be careful to not start the input string with a space, or you'll get the first word capitalized as well.

Comment: If a string has a single trailing space, this doesn't remove it. This looks good otherwise though!

Comment: huh, I tested for trailing spaces, but not for the *single* space! thanks for catching this.

Comment: I lifted your functions out of the `where` and gave them more meaningful names. Feel free to revert if you disagree.

Comment: thanks; interesting how the meaning comes out from the minimal solution. the skipping of the leading spaces still needs to be done separately, but it's a well known pattern already captured by `dropWhile isSpace`.

Comment: (to the casual reader: the bug caught by Joseph was fixed back then, if it's unclear).